# Will resetting PC with 'Remove Everything' affect non-OS Partition?

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning, reset

I have a *single SSD* with **2 Partitions** on my Windows 10 PC. I want to **reset** my *OS Partition* including the programs and other data. But I have data stored in the **other partition** which I want to keep. So if I use reset PC with "Remove Everything", will the other partition remain intact or will it be cleared as well?

Comment: That option should format non-OS partitions if you're not offered the [option](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/pc-reset-deletes-data-in-d-drive-partition/2044712d-0d21-4ec5-b69a-571628986eee) to select whether all partitions should be wiped. I'd recommend [capturing a WIM](https://superuser.com/a/1581804/529800) of the other partition prior to running Reset

Comment: Can I check whether I am offered the option or will it be a no-way-back?

Comment: You'd be offered the option before performing the Reset if you're using at least Windows 10 v 20H1 or newer _(what the answer in the previous link implies)_. I would capture a WIM of the other partition then perform the reset; that being said, if you're resetting due to issues being experienced, a Repair Install would be more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So if I use reset PC with "Remove Everything", will the other partition remain intact or will it be cleared as well?

You will be given an option to only touch the system partition.  As with any operation like this you should make appropriate backups[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1156769/how-does-windows-know-which-files-to-keep-during-reset/1156844#1156844)  **This answer only applies to systems running Windows 10 1909 or newer**

> - If you **select all drives**, this will erase all partitions/volumes on the Windows system disk.
> - If you select Windows drive, this will only erase the partition/volume Windows is installed on.
>
> [image]

After you make all of your choices you will be presented a summary of what will happen if you proceed with the Reset.

> [image]

Source: [How to Reset Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4130-reset-windows-10-a.html)